# Selectors do not get any state in angular (ngrx)

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Hello when I initialize my app and run it, I do not recieve any state in my selectors. Anyway I have set default initial state and I pass it to my reducer because they are the first thing which are subscribe to store when app is init and they provide initial state but my selector do not recieve any state. Also I have connected my state to my reducer using `StoreModule.forFeature(GlobalState.stateName, globalReducer)`, I even use the `ngrx` devtools but to track state but initial state keeps empty I really run out of ideas why this behavior is happening

I tried devtools to track my state, i tried to debug my selector and check when receive new values but this isn't happening.

Action:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

export const GlobalActionTypes = {
  HandleError: '[HttpResponseError] This will handle errors from serivces',
  LoadingScreen: '[Loading] This will show loading screen'
}

export class HandleErrorAction implements Action {
  readonly type: string = GlobalActionTypes.HandleError;
  constructor(public payload: HttpErrorResponse) { }
}

export class LoadingScreenAction implements Action {
  readonly type: string = GlobalActionTypes.LoadingScreen;
  constructor(public payload: boolean) { }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { GlobalActionTypes, LoadingScreenAction } from 
'../actions/global.actions';
import { GlobalState } from '../state/global.state';
import { ActionsMap } from 'src/app/core/models/reducer.model';

const initialState: GlobalState = {
  isLoading: false,
}

function loadingScreen(
  state: GlobalState,
  action: LoadingScreenAction): GlobalState {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    newState.isLoading = action.payload;
    return newState;
}

export const mapToReducer: ActionsMap<GlobalState> = {
  [GlobalActionTypes.LoadingScreen]: loadingScreen
}

export function globalReducer
  (state: GlobalState = initialState, action: Action) {

  mapToReducer[action.type] ? mapToReducer[action.type](state, action) : state
}
```

State:

```
export class GlobalState {
  static stateName: string = 'Global State'
  isLoading: boolean;
}
```

Selectors:

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { GlobalState } from '../state/global.state';

export const featureSelector = createFeatureSelector<GlobalState>
  (GlobalState.stateName);

export const loadingScreenSelector = createSelector(
  featureSelector,
  state => state.isLoading
);

AppModule imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    StoreModule.forFeature(GlobalState.stateName, globalReducer),
]
```

I have service which used to dispatch action one with true and one with false. Then I use `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR` and listen about requests. Every time when new request appear I use service to dispatch action with payload true. And when request is (doesn't matter succesful or no) I dispatch action with payload false. Actions are getting dispatched I even go in reducer when I check newState has correct payload. But selectors do not receive anything when state is mutated. I really tryed everything and I run out of ideas. Any suggestions are welcome. :(

Comment: why are you using forFeature to register your reducer? Do you have module that you are loading lazily?

Comment: Well my AppModule isn't loading lazily but this is not the problem for sure. And in this way i keep my consistens to all of the modules. I can see how my reducer is getting triggered so for sure make connections between state and reducer. The problem is state after reducer do not emit new state to selectors.

Comment: There can be different causes here, a reproduction would help me in order to give you an answer.